# Clone traffic to two network interfaces

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I have a process which normally sends UDP packets to either a unicast or multicast destination address.  In both cases the output interface is decided by the routing tables.

I'm looking for a way for the traffic to be "cloned" and sent out two interfaces. Something like this:

[image]

Since it is UDP, the traffic out both interfaces can (and should be) identical. So I don't think it is bridging or bonding.

Without modifying existing process is there way to do this on Linux (Centos 8)? (We could write a "splitter" process but that would add complexity and add latency.  Ideally if there is some kernel configuration technique we could use...

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising.  Will check it out!

Comment: A bridge configured properly would create exact duplicates, including Ethernet source and destination. So if you dismiss a bridge, that means you want to do something else that I can't know from your question. This looks like an XY problem to me. Can you describe why (not how) you want to do this?

Comment: A.B.  The "process" in the picture can only send to one IP address.  But customer wants to feed the output of "process" to two different systems for redundancy: main and backup. The systems are on different physical networks, so using multicast won't work.  If a bridge is simpler than using `iptables` and `tee` as suggested by Panki then please post some details on how to do it so we can investigate.

Comment: A Linux bridge can be configured to never learn mac addresses and (thus) always flood to all other ports. Likewise a Linux bonding interface can be configured in broadcast mode to achieve the same result. Anyway, if it aint broke, don't fix it: if iptables+tee does the job, that's fine.